# Lua switch like statement with case fallthroughs, accessible via C api

Tags: arrays, c, lua, lua-api

Trying to build a table that looks up effects depending on integer results.

Some of the results are in a range, like 1 to 5, but ultimately there's a bunch of em.

http://lua-users.org/wiki/SwitchStatement

Showcases some of it, but 'conveniently' did not see it necessary to mention anything about the C api.

So, how would I access the fields of a table/array with numerical indices from the C api?
At this point I'd be happy with a redundant solution that duplicates the entries to cover the ranges, the rub for me lies in the C api part of using a numerical index to get at a field.

```
Tables = {}


Tables.Effects = {
[1] = "effect 1"
.... 
}
```

If I had to accurately explain what I tried then I'd have to travel back in time and write down a myriad of permutations of blind groping around using

`lua_getglobal`

`lua_getfield`

`lua_pushnumber`

and the like

Perhaps this is simple enough to just hand out a spoonfeed?
The lua state is initialized. The file is error free and loaded via luaL_dofile, etc.

For the time being, to get work done, I'll be using a number to string approach, as horrible as that may be, because then I can use `lua_getfield`. Actually, goint to use a helper proxy function that then indexes the table via Lua itself.

Edit:
After trying a suggestion from the comments to use lua_geti
I failed with the following:

```
void accessTables(lua_State* L, int value)
{
    lua_getglobal(L, "Tables.Effects"); 
    lua_geti(L, -1,value); 
    if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) != 0) { // it actually is an array of functions, so calling them should be fine
        std::cout <<  "error running function `f':" << lua_tostring(L,-1)  << '\n';
    }

}
```

But even though the value passed is a valid index, I get the following error:
`| PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index a nil value)`

Edit: Thanks for the uncommented edit and  the downboats without any explanations as for why they were done, fellow redditors. My wifes boyfriend will now buy me a switch and ten funko pop statues.

Comment: In Lua 5.3+ you have `lua_geti` for integer indices.  In Lua 5.2- you should use `lua_pushnumber + lua_gettable`

Comment: I'm using 5.3, but `lua_geti` just gives me "PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to index a nil value) " Will update the question what I did with that.

Comment: You are trying to read `_G["Tables.Effects"][value]` instead of `_G["Tables"].Effects[value]`

Comment: Ahhh, I was thrown off by the way Lua does it in the scripts. Since you don't seem to want to, I'll have to write the answer to this question and accept it, huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ESkri put it, I treated the array wrongly by trying to use the 'dot' notation directly, when I should have gone through the steps manually.

Thus:

```
void accessTables(lua_State* L, int value)
{
    lua_getglobal(L, "Tables"); 
    lua_getfield(L,-1, "Effects"); // the manual step
    lua_geti(L, -1,value); //now it pushes the function onto the stack
    if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0) != 0) { //call it
        std::cout <<  "error running function `f':" << lua_tostring(L,-1)  << '\n';
    }
    lua_pop(L,2); //Only through experimentation I realized that the first getglobal stack entries with the table references had to be popped, but the function stack entry did not
//without the poppage, the stack grew by two entries each time I called it.
}
```

Did the trick